# Scripts multiplies in controllers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'am using node.js with sails.js for backend and angular.js for frontend.

In angular i am using one main controller and some childs conrtoller.

As you know, by default in sails.js, in file layout.ejs included all java scripts and css files between tags

```
<!--SCRIPTS--><!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

and

```
<!--STYLES--><!--STYLES END-->
```

Main content are included to `<%- body %>` tag

When i am lifted sails, go to browser and inspect "elements" i see some problem:

main controller (let it be "myApp") in angular generating html by using layout.ejs like main body (with all css and js), and then included controllers content.

Now problem:
Problem is that another child controllers of "myApp" generating by using layout.ejs too. And thats why some scripts included multiple times.

Example: 4 child controllers = 4 included of google.maps.api. Thats bad!! code so dirty!

And now question: how i can fix this issue, and make scripts and css included just one time?

Comment: Use a service to include the google.maps.api and share that service with the controllers. Services are singletons, only constructed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another layout let's call it `views/blanklayout.ejs` with just this content:

```
<%- body %>
```

Now, use this layout with all child controller views.
Do either

In your sails controller set layout to blanklayout: `res.locals.layout = 'blanklayout';`

OR you can also specify layout in routes e.g.

```
'GET /test': {
  controller: 'TestController',
  action: 'test',
  locals: {
    layout: 'blanklayout',
  },
},
```

PS: You can swap layouts also, meaning have just `<%- body %>` in `layout.ejs` and another layout (e.g. `mainLayout.ejs` to contain present content of layout.ejs. That way you'll not have to specify to use `mainLayout` only for main controller view.

Comment: Sorry, miss that. Thx for help!!))